# Celery rate_limit affecting multiple tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a setup with rabbitmq and celery, with workers running on 4 machines with 4 instances each. I have two task functions defined, which basically call the same backend function, but one of them named `process_transaction` with no rate_limit defined, and another called `slow_process_transaction`, with `rate_limit="6/m"`. The tasks go to different queues on rabbitmq, `slow` and `normal`.

The strange thing is the rate_limit being enforced for both tasks. If I try to change the rate_limit using `celery.control.rate_limit`, doing it with the `process_transaction` doesn't change the effective rate, and using the `slow_process_transaction` name changes the effective rate for both.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By reading the bucket source code I figured out celery implements rate limiting by sleeping the time delta after finishing a task, so if you mix tasks with different rate limits in the same workers, they affect each other.

Separating the workers solved my problem, but it's not the optimal solution.

You can separate the workers by using node names and named parameters on your celeryd call. For instance, you have nodes 'fast' and 'slow', and you want them to consume separate queues with concurrency 5 and 1 respectively:

```
celeryd <other opts> -Q:fast fast_queue -c:fast 5 -Q:slow slow_queue -c:slow 1
```

Comment: Looks like I bumped into the same problem. Thanks for the tip. Would be great to find out how exactly did you split your workers/queues if you don't mind sharing...

Comment: This doesn't work in celery 3.1:

$ celeryd worker -Q:fast fast_queue c:fast

("\nThe 'celeryd' command is deprecated, please use 'celery worker' instead:\n\n$ celery worker worker -Q:fast fast_queue c:fast\n\n",)

Unrecognized command-line arguments: worker, fast_queue, c:fast

Try --help?

Comment: Or, in the non-deprecated usage:
$ celery worker -Q:fast fast_queue c:fast 5 -Q:slow slow_queue -c:slow 1 => "Usage: celery worker [options] 

celery: error: option -c: invalid integer value: ':slow'"

Comment: does this still apply in 2019?

Comment: @PirateApp Yes. In fact, over the years I realized the problem is even more complicated, and having separate workers for distinct rates is unavoidable. I used eventlet for high concurrency, and created [this project](https://github.com/pjwerneck/bouncer) for global rate limiting,